# How can I activate the crossfade with a click instead of hover?

Tags: jquery, css, click, css-transitions, cross-fade

I'm working on my portfolio website and it's supposed to be a large accordion with pictures as the tabs. Since it's one long page, the tabs will not be links. I'm really new to jquery so I'm not sure how to make it work with my css. Basically, what's supposed to happen is that when you click the tab, the tab image transitions to the title as the accordion pulls the description down. I only want the transition to happen when it's clicked.

The transition can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jmf5436/k9PgC/)

It shows how the transition is supposed to work, but for now it can only be triggered by a hover state. Thanks!

html:

```
 <div class="img-container">
    <img src="images/fashion_spread.jpg">
         <div class="img-hidden">
             <img src="images/fashion_spread_bw.jpg">
         </div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
.img-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    float: left;
    display:list-item;
    position: relative;
}

.img-container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.img-hidden {
    bottom:0;
    position: absolute;
    opacity:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index:1000;
    transition:opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s;
}

.img-container:hover .img-hidden{
    opacity:1;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
    transition:opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `:hover` to `:active` but this would only apply your effect whilst the mouse was held down. I dont think you can do what you want with CSS alone.

Since you tagged jquery here is a jquery solution:

Change this:

```
.img-container:hover .img-hidden{
```

to this:

```
.img-container.active .img-hidden{
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.img-container').on('click',function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
    });

});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k9PgC/12/)

---

**EDIT**

In light of comments below, here is a full, working html page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                .img-container {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                    margin-left:auto;
                    float: left;
                    display:list-item;
                    position: relative;
                  }

                .img-container img {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: auto;
                }

               .img-hidden {
                   bottom:0;
                   position: absolute;
                   opacity:0;
                   filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
                   width: 100%;
                   height: 100%;
                   z-index:1000;
                   transition:opacity 0.5s;
                   -moz-transition:opacity 0.5s;
                   -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s;
                 }

                .img-container.active .img-hidden{
                    opacity:1;
                    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
                    transition:opacity 0.5s;
                    -moz-transition:opacity 0.5s;
                    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s;
                 }

            </style>

            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).ready(function() {

                    $('.img-container').on('click',function() {
                        $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
                    });

                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>

            <div class="img-container">
                <img src="images/fashion_spread.jpg">
                <div class="img-hidden">
                    <img src="images/fashion_spread_bw.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>

        </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: that's definitely one step closer. Since this image will eventually be an accordion tab, i need it to do the transition to "fashion spread" on click when it pulls down the rest of the accordion, and then when you click it again, it goes back to the picture when clicked again when the accordion closes. I think it's called toggling?

Comment: change `addClass('active')` to `toggleClass('active')`

Comment: hmm it's working perfect on jsfiddle but when i plug everything into dream weaver it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you loading jquery? You also need to wrap the code above in a domready block (see updated answer).

Comment: This is how I set it up in a JavaScript doc:  $(document).ready(function() {
$('.img-container').on('click',function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
});
});                                                                    I linked it in my html in the header with this:                          <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>

Comment: You also need to load the JQuery library. Add this to your page (before you load your script.js file) `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I have them in the header now like this but it still won't work:         <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>

Comment: See update. If you cant get this going I cant really help any further. Sorry. Good luck!

Comment: It'll alright thanks for everything. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

A css only solution using :target selector.

```
<div class="img-container">
  <a href="#target-hidden">
   <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wEYmgYC.jpg">
   <span id="target-hidden" class="img-hidden">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/XRUqimG.jpg">
   </span>
  </a>
</div>

#target-hidden:target {
  opacity:1;
  filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
  transition:opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:opacity 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Px52Y/10/

Comment: thanks! is there a way to make it so it goes back to the original image when clicked again?

Comment: You can just do the same for the hidden image to target the initial shown image.